# How to recompile when modified c++ header?

Tags: c++, header, makefile

I have a *.H c++ headers in include/c++ folder, but even if I modified these files, make doesn't make again, what can I modify my Makefile to remake when those files modified?

Comment: add the headers as a dependency to your build rule.

Comment: http://scottmcpeak.com/autodepend/autodepend.html

Comment: Are you writing your `Makefile` by hand or have a generator in use, like CMake?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're using GNU make and GCC, and building separate objects for each source (rather than building a program directly from all the sources) you can generate the necessary dependencies automatically. Add the following the the compiler's command-line arguments:

```
-MD -MP
```

`-MD` will generate a `.d` file alongside each object, containing make rules specifying all the headers it depends on. You could instead use `-MMD` to exclude system headers (ones included with `<>` rather than `""`), if you don't expect these to change. `-MP` will generate dummy rules to ensure the target is rebuilt if any of the headers are deleted.

Then include all the `.d` files from the makefile, using `-include` so it's not an error if they're missing. I do this by transforming the list of object files:

```
-include $(all_objs:.o=.d)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just make sure that your target depends on your headers.

```
your_app: $(SOURCES) $(HEADERS)
  $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(SOURCES) $(LIBS) -o$@
```

Comment: That's fine if you don't mind rebuilding everything when any header changes. It might be nice only to rebuild as much as you need, though.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: That's why I don't get why people still write their own Makefiles - unless they have a very good reason. You can get so much stuff wrong.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Agree. Usually I'm happy with this approach when doing some research. In real life projects I prefer to use automatic makefile generation and dependency tracking.

Comment: It's useless to write a makefile like this.  Why don't you just write a shell script that runs the compiler?  There's no advantage to this "makefile" over that shell script.

Comment: http://www.brickshelf.com/gallery/mikezang/brickos/makefile is my Makefile (not created by me, just a copy from original) in my folder. it includes http://www.brickshelf.com/gallery/mikezang/brickos/makefile.common and  http://www.brickshelf.com/gallery/mikezang/brickos/makefile.user, what can I do? I tried to add CINC  =-I$(BRICKOS_ROOT)/include -I$(BRICKOS_ROOT)/include/lnp -I. -I$(BRICKOS_ROOT)/include/*/*.H, it doesn't work.

Comment: @mikezang check your .depend file, there should be your dependencies in the form of: file.o: header1.h header2.h. If it's not being created make sure you have unset NODEPS environment variable.